# Why does /usr/libexec/java_home not print out anything?

Tags: macos, zsh, java-home

I have macOS Big Sur (11.0.1) installed and I wonder why the `/usr/libexec/java_home` command does not print out anything at all in zsh. Only using the -h option prints out the help but any other option -V, -X, ...does not print out anything. Why?

Maybe it's worth to be noticed: I installed JENV and doctor says:

```
% jenv doctor
[OK]    JAVA_HOME variable probably set by jenv PROMPT
[OK]    Java binaries in path are jenv shims
[OK]    Jenv is correctly loaded
```

echo $JAVA_HOME says:

```
~HOME/.jenv/versions/system
```

This command prints out nothing:

```
xxx ~ % /usr/libexec/java_home -V
xxx ~ %
```

Installed JDKs:

```
xxx ~ % jenv versions
* system (set by /Users/du-it/.jenv/version)
  11
  11.0
  11.0.2
  15
  openjdk64-11.0.2
  openjdk64-15
```

Answer (score 0):

The instructions of how to install jEnv are not completely comprehensive, I think. I have to find out with [Manage your Java JDKs](https://betweentwoparens.com/jenv#set-a-jdk-version-via-jenv)

that it seems to be essential to run this command:

```
jenv global 11.0.2.
```

Now the `java_home` command prints out a valuable result.